# How to handle libnodave error message with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, pascal, plc, siemens, libnodave

I have a function that reads some values from Siemens PLC using `libnodave.dll` and nodave unit but I cannot figure out the error output. I am on purpose forcing to go in error and what I get from `AError := string(daveStrerror(readResult));` is an incomprehensible message:

> `'桴'#$2065'敤楳敲'#$2064'摡牤獥'#$2073'獩戠祥湯'#$2064'楬業⁴潦'#$2072'桴獩倠䍌'`

Maybe 2064/2065/2073/2072 all represent a different error code which I have to handle independently? And why chinese? My machine is set up in Italian language.

Comment: I guess, that unit is not made for Unicode and your are using a Delphi version above D2007.

Comment: Please be aware that these values are hex values because the of ``$`` sign!

Comment: This is just the classic issue of interpreting UTF-16 text as if it were 8 bit ANSI text. Which Delphi version are you using?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i am using Delphi 12

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. It's the other way around. This is 8 bit text and you are treating it as UTF-16. Do you know what encoding this library is using? Is it ANSI or UTF-8? And are you familiar with text encodings?>

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sorry, i don't know the encoding type that libnodave uses, i am not so familiar with it, just doing some tests... should i write a function to convert this string?

Comment: step 1, find out how the text is encoded, this will be documented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly the library works with ANSI/ASCII chars. The *nodave.pas* unit works with `PChar`, which is `PAnsiChar` in Delphi versions up to D2007 and `PWideChar` above. You need to adjust the *nodave.pas* unit to handle that.

You might get away with replacing all `PChar` with `PAnsiChar`, but I haven't inspected it more deeply.

Comment: Clearly??? I mean we can see it's an 8 bit encoding but we don't know more than that. Could be UTF-8.

Comment: From nodave.h: `EXPORTSPEC char * DECL2 daveStrerror(int code);` and S7 doesn't support UTF-8.

Comment: In addition, all available error messages are plain ASCII.

Comment: Thanks @UweRaabe i replaced all PChar with PAnsiChar and it works.